# mysqldump without adding USE database_name

Tags: mysql

I am looking for an option/idea how could I get rid of the statement 'USE database_name' when using mysqldump ?
I manage to get rid of creating DB only.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an actual option for the mysqldump command but you could always just run the output through a filter like **sed**. For example:

```
mysqldump | sed -e '/^CREATE DATABASE/d' -e '/^USE `/d' >dumpFile.txt
```

Or if you have the dump file you would do it as:

```
sed -e '/^CREATE DATABASE/d' -e '/^USE `/d' <dumpFile.txt >cleanedUpDumpFile.txt
```

The second way might be better. If there is not too much data you can do:

```
diff dumpFile.txt cleanedUpDumpFile.txt | less
```

To verify that only the lines you wanted were deleted. If everything looks OK you can go with the first way to just generate what you want.